# How to locate the file in which the method is implement in android binder

Tags: android, android-binder

When I read the source codes of Android binder.c which is located at.
`/frameworks/native/cmds/servicemanager/binder.c`.
I am confused about where to find the implement of open invocation in the codes below, is there anyone have any idea to help?

````
struct binder_state *binder_open(const char* driver, size_t mapsize)
{
    struct binder_state *bs;
    struct binder_version vers;

    bs = malloc(sizeof(*bs));
    if (!bs) {
        errno = ENOMEM;
        return NULL;
    }

    bs->fd = open(driver, O_RDWR | O_CLOEXEC);
    if (bs->fd < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr,"binder: cannot open %s (%s)\n",
                driver, strerror(errno));
        goto fail_open;
    }

    if ((ioctl(bs->fd, BINDER_VERSION, &vers) == -1) ||
        (vers.protocol_version != BINDER_CURRENT_PROTOCOL_VERSION)) {
        fprintf(stderr,
                "binder: kernel driver version (%d) differs from user space version (%d)\n",
                vers.protocol_version, BINDER_CURRENT_PROTOCOL_VERSION);
        goto fail_open;
    }

    bs->mapsize = mapsize;
    bs->mapped = mmap(NULL, mapsize, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, bs->fd, 0);
    if (bs->mapped == MAP_FAILED) {
        fprintf(stderr,"binder: cannot map device (%s)\n",
                strerror(errno));
        goto fail_map;
    }

    return bs;

fail_map:
    close(bs->fd);
fail_open:
    free(bs);
    return NULL;
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of `open` happens in the Linux kernel, specifically the Android IPC subsystem.

The following struct holds the function pointers for the binder device node ([reference](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.9.11/source/drivers/android/binder.c#L6058)):

```
const struct file_operations binder_fops = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .poll = binder_poll,
    .unlocked_ioctl = binder_ioctl,
    .compat_ioctl = compat_ptr_ioctl,
    .mmap = binder_mmap,
    .open = binder_open,
    .flush = binder_flush,
    .release = binder_release,
};
```

For the `open` operation, the struct holds a pointer to `binder_open` ([reference](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.9.11/source/drivers/android/binder.c#L5203))

In `init_binder_device`, the `binder_fops` struct is assigned to the device node ([reference](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.9.11/source/drivers/android/binder.c#L6069)).

Comment: I suppose you are correct. but Android is based on Linux kernel, theoretically, these codes should be in AOSP, but it seems not according your reply. By the way, is there any article which explains what is binder and how does it works completely?